# should i use BELONGS_TO, HAS_ONE o both in a self related table?

Tags: yii

I have a table 'person' with a self relationships one to many, 'mother' and 'father', whom of course are persons. So 'person' table has two optional fields, 'mother_id' and 'father_id' pointing to other rows in the same table.

should i use  BELONGS_TO, HAS_ONE o both?

Is important to remark that mother and father are optionals, in terms of the system an orphan is a valid entity, and of course a mother or father has no specific distintion other than the existent persons that point to him/her as father/mother.

Its also important to mention that for the sistem is irrelevant to know someone's childs, it's only relevant know the parents of a given person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination like this:

```
return array(
    'father' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Person', 'father_id'),
    'mother' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Person', 'mother_id'),
    'mothersChildren' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Person', 'mother_id'),
    'fathersChildren' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Person', 'father_id'),
);
```

So you want a `HAS_MANY`, not a `HAS_ONE` for your children, as each person may have more than one child.

You also see, that the problematic relation is the children relation: You'd have to use a JOIN like `LEFT JOIN person c ON t.mother_id=c.id OR t.father_id=c.id` which you can't define with Yii's relations. So you can define two relations and write a getter like `getChildren()` to create the union over `mothersChildren` and `fathersChildren` relations.

Answer (score 1):

`BELONGS_TO` is usually used in reverse relation(child=>parent) while `HAS_ONE` is used in forward-relation (parent=>child). Therefore you best bet is , in my suggestion `HAS_ONE`.

The other important concept in this case is the concept of `Weak Entity`. `Weak Entity` does not exists without the `parent` or `strong entity`. Whenever you are referring back from `Weak Entity` to `Strong Entity` always use `BELONGS_TO` and `HAS_ONE` in other case.

Example of weak entity:`UserProfile`

`User` `HAS_ONE` `UserProfile`

A `UserProfile`  `BELONGS_TO` A `User`.

Rememeber `UserProfile` does not exist without the `User` record, hence its weak entity.

In you case I an not sure when you say  `one to many, 'mother' and 'father'`

However some possible relationships could be:

1. Person:Mother::1:1
2. Person:Father::1:1
3. Person:Children::1:M

If you are talking about the 3rd case, the relationship will be `BELONGS_TO`